# Mysql extract first letter of each word in a specific column

Tags: mysql, acronym

I want to create an acronym column in a table. I want to be grab the first letter of each word from a 'name' column, capitalize it, then concatenate all into an 'acronym' column.

Any easy way to grab first letters?

Comment: Are you asking if there's any easy way to do this with just SQL?

Comment: Yeah, or any quick and easy way. I have a table with 170+ rows that I added an acronym column to. I was just looking for a quick way to grab a 'name' and use the first letter of each word as the acronym.

Comment: I think you'd need some higher level programming constructs for something that wouldn't twist your mind around too much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an "improved" function, allowing to filter only wanted characters thanks to a regular expression.

- function `initials` does the actual job, you have to specify the regular expression
- function `acronym` does the job keeping Alpha-numeric characters only

(Use `upper`, `lower` or `ucase` functions on the output if necessary)
.

```
delimiter $$
drop function if exists `initials`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `initials`(str text, expr text) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
begin
    declare result text default '';
    declare buffer text default '';
    declare i int default 1;
    if(str is null) then
        return null;
    end if;
    set buffer = trim(str);
    while i <= length(buffer) do
        if substr(buffer, i, 1) regexp expr then
            set result = concat( result, substr( buffer, i, 1 ));
            set i = i + 1;
            while i <= length( buffer ) and substr(buffer, i, 1) regexp expr do
                set i = i + 1;
            end while;
            while i <= length( buffer ) and substr(buffer, i, 1) not regexp expr do
                set i = i + 1;
            end while;
        else
            set i = i + 1;
        end if;
    end while;
    return result;
end$$

drop function if exists `acronym`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `acronym`(str text) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
begin
    declare result text default '';
    set result = initials( str, '[[:alnum:]]' );
    return result;
end$$
delimiter ;
```

Example1:

```
select acronym('Come Again? That Cant Help!');
```

Outputs:

> CATCH

Example2:

```
select initials('Come Again? That Cant Help!', '[aeiou]');
```

Outputs:

> oeAaaae

Comment: Could you explain more about how I can install this function? When I enter it into the SQL section in PhpMyAdmin it returns the error "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)."

Answer (score 1):

String manipulation of this kind is not what SQL is designed for, unless you want to write a stored procedure or UDF for it.

SQL isn't really suited for *string manipulation* of this sort. You ***may*** do it *somehow* but why would you when better tools are available elsewhere? I went on a long search on Google to find such a *query statement* but I couldn't. Just use the following *function* to achieve what you want.

```
drop function if exists initials;
delimiter ||
create function initials(str text) returns text
begin
    declare result text default '';
    declare i int default 1;

    if(str is null) then
        return null;
    end if;

    set result = upper(substr(str, 1, 1));

    while(i <= length(str)) do
        if (substring(str, i, 1) = ' ')
        then
            set result = concat(result, upper(substr(str, i+1, 1)));
        end if;
       set i = i + 1;
    end while;

    return ucase(result);
end;
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little late to the game, but I wanted to offer up a non-function way of doing this for those of you creating a view or a .sql file for periodic use:

```
SELECT
    @spaces:= length(fi.FacilityName) - length(replace(fi.FacilityName,' ','')) as spaces,
    concat(left(fi.FacilityName,1),
        if(@spaces > 0, substring(fi.FacilityName,@pos:=locate(' ',fi.FacilityName)+1,1),''),
        if(@spaces > 1, substring(fi.FacilityName,@pos:=locate(' ',fi.FacilityName, @pos)+1,1),''),
        if(@spaces > 2, substring(fi.FacilityName,@pos:=locate(' ',fi.FacilityName,@pos)+1,1),''),
        if(@spaces > 3, substring(fi.FacilityName,@pos:=locate(' ',fi.FacilityName,@pos)+1,1),''),
        if(@spaces > 4, substring(fi.FacilityName,@pos:=locate(' ',fi.FacilityName,@pos)+1,1),'')) as initials
from facilityInfo fi
```

It's two steps, and you have to include a conditional substring() line for every word you anticipate being in the string, but that is just a copy, paste, and increment of the comparison value for @spaces.  My requirements for doing this may be a little looser than some, however.  Regardless, it works and causes no noticeable speed issues.

Answer (score 0):

This should get all the first letters into a result set:

```
SELECT UPPER(SUBSTR(name, 0, 1)) FROM the_table
```

Concatenating them all into a single acronym would, I think, require a procedure of some kind. I don't think it can be done in a statement.

Comment: This only returns the first letter of the first word? Right?

Comment: Then change it to `SELECT UPPER(CONCAT(SUBSTR(col1, 0, 1), SUBSTR(col2, 0, 1))) as acronym FROM the_table`

Comment: As noted below, if COL1 contains "My Big Fat String", I need ACRNM to be "MBFS"... the first letter of each word from a single column.

Comment: @SamGrant - Ah. I misinterpreted your requirement. Unlike MS SQL, MySQL does not have a function to split a string at delimiters. You will definitely need to write a procedure. If this is a one-time thing, you are probably best off retrieving the data into a program, computing the acronym, and inserting it back into the db. If you want to do it in MySQL exclusively, there's a discussion thread [here on the MySQL forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,78776,78776) on this subject that can get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [LEFT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) and [UPPER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper)?

Comment: Since the string could be My Big Fat String, LEFT only will return 'M', I need "MBFS"...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( ' Bart Van Eynde', ' (.)[^ ]+', '\\1' ); -- 'BVE'
```

- Before starting add a space before your string
- ' (.)[^ ]+' = Start looking for space + something (and save it) + ignore the rest if it is not a space
- '\\1' only write the 'something' back

in a query:

```
SELECT UPPER( REGEXP_REPLACE( CONCAT(' ', col1), ' (.)[^ ]+', '\\1' ) ) from table1;
```