# Query to find all words in a field that contains the letters

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a query that can find all the records from a field contains the letters.
For example suppose a state field contains a record value "New York" and another record conatains NY. Now i am searching for NY or New york will return these 2 records. What will be the query.
Currently i am using

```
like %New York%" or "%NY%"
```

Any suggestion

Comment: Your query looks perfect, what do you expect as result.

Comment: I expects if the query has %New York%" it will automatically works as "%NY%" also

Comment: You mean, if somebody searches with 'New York' then query should return all the values matching with 'New York' and 'NY'

Comment: It looks touch to handle such situation in MySQL query as there are versatile combinations for every state.
And using  `LIKE` clause for all those combination are very costly and time consuming.
But would like to suggest you to provide a select list to user and based on it you run your query, it will be fast and of course precise.

Comment: yes but the table does not have much records and select list will take more time and also states not only usa in many countries as well

Comment: just a thought, if database is yours why don't you provide selectlist to users from where they can input the state at the first place?

Answer (score 0):

No your query is not correct as it searches for anything containing New York or NY.
So if there is PENNY that will be matched although it shouldn't be....

Your query must be something like this.

```
SELECT * from TABLE where field in ('NEW YORK','NY')
```

Now to fetch acronym,you can use

```
delimiter $$
drop function if exists `initials`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `initials`(str text, expr text) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
begin
    declare result text default '';
    declare buffer text default '';
    declare i int default 1;
    if(str is null) then
        return null;
    end if;
    set buffer = trim(str);
    while i <= length(buffer) do
        if substr(buffer, i, 1) regexp expr then
            set result = concat( result, substr( buffer, i, 1 ));
            set i = i + 1;
            while i <= length( buffer ) and substr(buffer, i, 1) regexp expr do
                set i = i + 1;
            end while;
            while i <= length( buffer ) and substr(buffer, i, 1) not regexp expr do
                set i = i + 1;
            end while;
        else
            set i = i + 1;
        end if;
    end while;
    return result;
end$$
drop function if exists `acronym`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `acronym`(str text) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
begin
    declare result text default '';
    set result = initials( str, '[[:alnum:]]' );
    return result;
end$$
delimiter ;
```

So,your final query will be something like this.

```
SELECT * from TABLE where field in ('NEW YORK',select acronym('Come Again? That Cant Help!'))
```

Source:-  [Mysql extract first letter of each word in a specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672815/mysql-extract-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-specific-column)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the logic that you want is:

```
col like '%New York%' or col like '%NY%'
```

or, if you want to use regular expressions:

```
col regexp 'New York|NY'
```

Answer (score 0):

Select * from table where col like '%N' or col like '%n'