# How to get the first letters form the string in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called leaves

```
id    leave_name     status

 1   Casual Leave     0

 2   Sick Leave       0
```

I need to get the get the first letters from leave name like **CL, SL**

I tried LEFT() but the string length is not pre-defined.

Comment: Although you can do this in sql using substring_index(), I would do this in the application logic. Mysql's string manipulation functions are not that efficient. Also, if you have a leave name with more than 2 words, it is very difficult to handle.

Comment: this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672815/mysql-extract-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-specific-column

Answer (score 3):

There is an obvious edge case here, which is what should happen if the leave name should have more than two terms.  I assume that you only want the initials from the first two words, regardless of how many appear.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN INSTR(leave_name, ' ') > 0 THEN
         CONCAT(LEFT(leave_name, 1),
                SUBSTRING(leave_name, INSTR(leave_name, ' ') + 1, 1))
         ELSE LEFT(leave_name, 1) END AS initials
FROM yourTable;
```

I also added coverage for an edge case when only one word be present.  In this case, we just take the single initial of that word.

### Demo